# Android realm executeTransactionAsync OnSuccess() taking too long

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

the problem that I am having is the following: For some reason onSuccess() is being call 2 minutes after all the code inside execute() is executed. Not sure why is taking that long.

CODE:

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    Log.e("time-pre", Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
                    RealmResults<TVRealm> tvRealms = realm.where(TVRealm.class)
                            .equalTo("favorite", true)findAll();
                    Log.e("time-post", Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());

                }
            }, new OnSuccess() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.e("time-on-success", Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
                    listener.onDataUpdate(tvList);
                }
            });
```

This is not happening on all devices, my understanding is that is only happening on devices that were using a really old realm db (like 0.84 on gradle) and after updating is causing this.

Does anyone has any clue about this issue?

Comment: What version did you update to ? 4.0.0-RC1?

Comment: To the last one stable: classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.7.2"

Comment: Is that code correct? Because the transaction does not appear to do anything besides running a query? That said, without more information, it is hard to tell, but two reasons could exist. 1) Something is saturating the looper with other events preventing Realms onSuccess to reach the main thread (highly unlikely). 2) You have a Realm object tree with cyclic references, it can sometimes cause our change notifications to be slow. The workaround there is to replace them with `@LinkingObjects` to break the cycle.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Have you finally fixed this and do you remember how?